# Firebase android distribution won't allow applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, firebase, continuous-integration

When running `./gradlew appDistributionUploadDevDebug`  I get an error saying it can't find the app.

The culprit is having `applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"` in my dev flavor. Removing it allows the apk to be uploaded, but then the artifact wouldn't be built properly. For the record I plan using only the dev flavor for internal distribution.

I get an error message saying I should enable app distribution, but since this is done on a "firebase project" level and it's done for the main flavor I can't do it again.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadDevDebug'.
> App Distribution could not find your app 1:xxxxxxxxx:android:0b3f<xxxxxxxxx>.
  Make sure to onboard your app by pressing the "Get started" button on the App Distribution page in the Firebase console:

        https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/appdistribution
```

Documenting this as a bug, I'll add a reply since I found a workaround.

Edit: expanded name of gradlew task that was shortened. Though it works it may make for easier searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround: 
To fix open `app/google-services.json` and look for the `mobilesdk_app_id` key for the main package name.

For example in my case I noticed that `1:xxxxxxx:android:0b3f<xxxxxxx>` was the value for the package with the `.dev` suffix, while the main package name (without `.dev`) shows under `1:xxxxxxx:android:7eb88<xxxxxxxx>`

So heading to `app/build.gradle`, the `firebaseAppDistribution` block would look like this

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
     appId = "1:xxxxxxxx:android:7eb88<xxxxxxxx>"
```

I still think this is a bug in firebase distribution. Sounds like the distribution gradle code is picking the right value, but the distribution server is not compatible.

BTW When the developer wants/needs to have 2 separate firebase projects you need to download 2 separate `google-services.json` files, and place them in the appropriate flavor folders. I also have a (2nd and 3rd) app that shares a project with that setup, but haven't added firebase distribution yet to check how it behaves.

For reference, my workaround worked while providing a `serviceCredentialsFile`. I also tried using the web token authentication but my results were inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that would be the case, but it turns out that you have to enable app distribution for *each* apk (buildType and/or flavor).

When selecting a project on the firebase console, the page automatically selects one of the apps and I was just enabling app distribution for that one.

There's a dropdown at the top where you can select another app (build/flavor), and you have to go to each one individually and enable app distribution.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I assume that in your case each flavour is a different app, then the error message is correct. That's not my case, so people may have to go with the hack if they're in my case.

Comment: Yes, but I'm also using buildTypes with suffix, and it's working fine. I'm adding the suffix in the buildType and not the flavor, though. I'm not sure that is your case

Comment: that's right, I do it on `productFlavors`. That's good info you have for bugfixing though.